# Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Tags: android, adt, android-logcat

I installed the latest version of the SDK (r21) and ADT 21.0.0. I tried simple code, and it works well, but now I get a warning in [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) that did not appear in the previous versions:

> Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

I googled it, and I found *[Issue 39723: Emulator spams LogCat with "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" message](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723)*.

What does it mean?

Comment: it means there's a bug in the latest SDK. make sure and star the issue to vote for it getting fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem, should I downgrade the application ?

Answer (score 477, accepted):

I just ran into this problem, too. As a workaround I'm filtering the `LogCat` output with the following expression on the `by Log Message` field of the filter:

```
^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$
```

Otherwise it is so spammed it's almost useless.

Following  [Laksh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737392/laksh) suggestion, if you want to filter this always without having to always write it on the `Search for messages` field:

1. Goto your `Logcat`
2. In the `Saved Filters` part on the left, click on the `Edit selected logcat filter` (If Saved Filters is not visible then click on Display Saved Filters View in the Logcat)
3. There, in the by Log Message field, enter `^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$`.

Comment: will you please tell me how to write this in Log.

Comment: Goto your Logcat, and in the `Saved Filters` part, click on `Edit selected logcat filter`. There in the `by Log Message` field enter `^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$`.
If `Saved Filters` is not visible then click on `Display saved filters view` in the Logcat.

Comment: This is a nice workaround for those of us using Intel images (as opposed to ARM, where this is supposed to be fixed)

Comment: I'm still learning regular expressions, and I'm a bit confused by this. I understand the components (start of line, negative look-ahead, any characters, string literal, any characters, end of line), but I don't understand why some of it is necessary. Doesn't a regex return any line that contains a match, so why do we need `^`, `.*`, and `$`? Why not just `(?!nativeGetEnabledTags)`? (p.s. this doesn't work)

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of `grep` which is nice and searches the line by default.  The answer to: "Doesn't a regex return any line that contains a match..." is NO.

Answer (score 59):

It's a bug in the emulator System Image for API 17.

At the moment, your workarounds are the following:

**If you DON'T need API level 17**

- Use an emulator with API 16 (or lower)...
- ...or higher (API 19 for instance, tested to solve the problem too).

**If you DO need API level 17**

- Use a real device: Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Nexus 10.
- Use the LogCat filter suggested by Hendrik. You'll have to edit every single filter you have, though (If you want to fix them all).

Comment: I use Nexus 7 Real Device, but the bug still appears in Logcat... Hendrik's workaround is the best for time being..

Comment: Same with a Nexus 4 and a Galaxy Nexus with 4.2.1. Though workaround is somewhat limited: other logs tend to disappear rather quickly.

Comment: It seems that those real devices also have the buggy system image. I guess that your only workaround in that case in the log filter.

Comment: No needed it's lower. I had the same problem, I run an emulator running Android 4.4.2 API Level 19 and it also solved the problem.

Answer (score 18):

The link which you referred to has the answer.
It is a bug introduced in the latest revision of the tools.
In the followup comments you can read that a google representative says a fix is on the way.

Answer (score 15):

Update the `ARM EABI v7a System Image` from `Android SDK Manager` and the warning wont be seen any more .. !! :)

Yes. This works only for ARM EABI System Image and not for Intel image.

**Update**

Seems like there is a Update available for the `Intel x86 Atom System Image` for *API 18* which fixes the issue (I have not tried it though). A [`link`](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-jelly-bean-43-installation-instructions-manually) to manually install the system image. Ofcourse its also available in Android SDK Manager.

But its only for Android 4.3.  The 4.2.x developers might still have to wait for a fix..!

Comment: Has no effect, don't bother

Comment: It has a effect! After the System Image Update, the bug is not seen. If there's no effect in your case, then also try updating your `adt plugin` and `android sdk`.

Comment: No - I have latest versions of everything, and rebooted the machine, and the bug is still there.

Comment: I still see this in the intel image myself.

Comment: Updating the ARM EABI m7a System Image worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: I think it works for some and for some it doesn't.. It worked for me too..!! And I also tried the system image update on 3 other android installed systems, and it worked for all of them..!!

Comment: Reproduced the same issue on Intel Atom(X86) Image API 17, 4.2.2                                                                      ADT version 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685. Everything should be latest.

Comment: This is not a solution for **Intel** image. ARM EABI is not for Intel, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with Intel x86 Atom images and "nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" is fixed with the release of the Android 4.3 (API 18) Intel x86 Atom image. I just tested it and can confirm that.

With ARM images this was fixed some time ago, I know ...

Answer (score 4):

Since these mesasages are tagged with the `Trace` tag, you can use simpler expression to filter them `by Log Tag` field:

```
^(?!Trace)
```

That's it.

Btw, I also see these messages on the real device (Fly IQ4410).

Answer (score 4):

I was getting lots of similar messages, so I needed better filters. Add these filters to the LogCat:

**By log tag:**

```
^(?!.*(GN_FW_TextView|GN_FW_Editor|SurfaceTextureClient|skia|AbsListView|Provider/Settings|InputMethodManager|jdwp)).*$
```

**By log message:**

```
^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added the `^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$`  filter, but you can see how few it helps me:

[image]

from 1157 is filtered a few and 799 bypassed same ratio, but a bit bigger numbers:

[image]

I needed to add the "SpamFilter" to be able to use the Logcat:

[image]

by Log Tag:

```
 ^(?!Trace|ADB_SERVICES|BufferQueue|wpa_supplican|SurfaceFlinger|Settings/BW|Bluetooth HS/HF)
```

by Application Name:

```
^(?!com.android.systemui|system_process)
```

For me it made a bit usable the Logcat.