# logcat filled with message "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" - how to get rid of this?

Tags: android, android-logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

I have just installed the latest version of SDK (r21) and ADT 21.0.0. I shifted my project from the eclipse, I was using previously to the newer version. After shifting the project i clicked on the `Run` button to test the application, and suddenly i found that the whole `logcat` was filled with the message

`Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0`

I just 10 minutes the number of this kind of messages reached more than 10,000 and i am fed up with this. Please tell me how can i remove this message from appearing in the logcat. And i want to stop this message from appearing as well

`Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Please help.

Comment: just grep your logs if these logs are not related to your app

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check this answer: [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

Add this filter to the LogCat: `^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$`

It is a bug introduced in the latest revision of the tools... Google is working on a fix on the next version.

Comment: @NeTelnStEiN but until the update is released.. how can i remove this right now??

Comment: Add this filter to the logcat: ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$

Comment: Hiding the message does not fix the issue,...

Comment: JPM yes, but only Google can fix it.. so that the best we can do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NeTeInStEiN's answer regarding the nativeGetEnabledTags issue, I have the same problem and the following in the logcat filter works to hide them (as mentioned in comments):

```
^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$
```

With regards to the other issue, I have tracked it down to being an emulator that doesn't have enough ram set to cope with running Jelly-bean (or which ever droid version). When I run my app on the emulator I get slow responses (and that error), when I run it on an actual device I don't see the messages.