# Intent Creation for Android

Tags: android, android-intent

This is just a beginners question, but even with the help of others' questions (which did increase my knowledge), I still am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have run SupWorld class directly (through the manifest) and it worked, so I believe the problem is I am not calling the class correctly.  I have tried all of the suggestions I have found, but every time it tells me "Unfortunately, Test Code has stopped." in the emulator.  (Test Code is the name of my project.)  I have left some of the failed attempts as comments in my code to help determine the problem.  I of course tried using "this" for my content without success.  Any helpful knowledge would be appreciated!  Thanks.

```
package com.evorlor.testcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//  Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//      context = this;

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SupWorld.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // @Override
    // public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    // return true;
    // }

}
```

My logCat (I am unfamiliar with what logCat is and does or how to use it.  I exported it as a text file and this is all that came up.  Let me know if this is not what you are looking for:

```
12-10 21:11:38.013: W/Trace(1094): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Thanks for help everyone....I think it is a manifest issue.  How do I declare SupWorld class in my manifest?

Comment: Did you try `ManinActivity.this` instead of `this` and `getApplicationContext()`? And uncomment `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` if that is in fact the correct layout for MainActivity

Comment: yes codeMagic and coming up A--C

Comment: @SamuelKnox Post *everything* your log outputs in red. Also, Rotem might be right, check your manifest.

Comment: @SamuelKnox : see this post possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562826/logcat-filled-with-message-unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0-how

Comment: thanks prosper, but definately not a duplicate i dont think

Comment: @SamuelKnox : not duplicate but issue is same  for more info you can see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723

Comment: For future reference, you can change the log type to 'error' by clicking the dropdown box, click in the logcat and 'ctrl+c' then paste in your post and format it with code brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you declare `SupWorld` in the manifest?

Comment: hmmm...i dont think i did!  how do i do that? :) is it like this?:              android:name="com.evorlor.testcode.SupWorld"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: <activity android:name=".SupWorld" /> inside your <application> tag. example: http://theblaine.com/2011/07/sample-androidmanifest-xml-file/

Comment: why would you boot it? you just have to re-install the app. if you can't see the change just do project -> clean (assuming you're using eclipse). this is a tip for every time you change some of the resources and don't see it.

Comment: How do I declare .SupWorld and .MainActivity?  I want it to run MainActivity as its primary, and then run .SupWorld through MainActivity

Comment: look at the sample manifest that i linked. it has multiple activities in it, but only the first one has the <intent-filter> tag that makes it the default activity.

Comment: Oh thanks.  I was unaware that there could be multiple class activities.  I put it somewhere it compiles, but I am not sure if I am just skipped over MainActivity and running SupWorld.  It runs, but I get this error in my console:  [2012-12-10 16:31:30 - TestCode] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.evorlor.testcode/.MainActivity }
[2012-12-10 16:31:30 - TestCode] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front    Is it all good?

Comment: first your current whole application code is right this is just R21 api emulator error or this error also occur some new sumsung devices.this is not any programming issue. and if you found this issue also in any new situation  then you can also post this issue in google current issue list

Comment: this happens because you didn't make any change to the code so the emulator just keeps the old app version. just add some spaces in one of your java classes and recompile the app. :)

Comment: I am still getting this error, but at least it runs. thanks everyone!:   [2012-12-10 16:39:09 - TestCode] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Answer (score 0):

From the first look look like it should be like this, paste logcat if it doesen't work

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SupWorld.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `MainActivity.class`?, definitely not. If anything, `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: i am having trouble getting my logcat to a text form. i can only get it to show the one line. how do i display? sorry. i am new to logcat