# Read a text value and spinner value

Tags: android

I have the following MainActivity.java file currently running on Eclipse.

My intention is to get the user input and the spinner value and form a url like `www.ex.com?title=(user_inpu)&title_type=(spinner_input)`.

As of now I am hung on this part. How do I get the text value from EditText and Spinner?

I have tried writing this code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());
                }
            });


Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.title_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});

}


}
```

I am getting a small error:

> The method v(string, String) is undefined for MainActivity.java.

I have tried replacing the `Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());` to `Log.v("EditText", MainActivity.this.edit.getText().toString());`, but the error still persists.

How do I get rid of that? And in general, will this code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not importing the right `Log` class.

Just replace

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
```

by

```
import android.util.Log;
```

And you probably want to make your `spinner` a member of the activity (just like the button and the text field) so that you can access it from any listener.

I mean:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn;
    private EditText edit;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());
                Log.v("Spinner", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.title_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I got it. Infact just seconds before you answered.:-) By saying making spinner a member of the activity, I guess I need to insert the spinner code inside the btn.setOnCLickListener() right?

Comment: My LogCat doesn't display the text input neither the spinner value. It says Unexpected Value..Where should I check for the outputs??

Comment: But why did you change the extends Activity to extends PreferenceActivity. With preferenceActivity, i see a lot of errors. When i switched back to extends Activity, i see no errors..
But where am i supposed to see the output? My logCat doesnt display it..

Comment: You should see your input values in LogCat when clicking the button

Comment: Under the text field of Logcat, all i see is Unexpected Value from nativeGetEnabledTags and it keeps on running...BTW the two } you added after spinner.setAdapter(adapter, I have them after the 
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener method. It is ok right?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

Comment: I checked that link, still my logcat is givving errors, instead of the input and spinner values. The 2 { you have put, are they on the right places??

Comment: Going by your addition, Should i put the method spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener right after your code or is it not necessary ??

Comment: `setOnItemSelectedListener` is only necessary if you want to trigger an action when spinner's selection changes