# Unexpected value from nativegetenableTags 0

Tags: android

I am creating same thread for this issue. Because I want to go further step in this problem.
Problem is I get a warning

```
Unexpected value from nativegetenableTags 0
```

I found some discussions about this [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

I downgraded the SDK to 16 to but still I get the same error. what is the least sdk level I have to downgrade my application? Isn't there any alternative solution for this?? :(

Comment: see this link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723

Comment: Since the accepted answer is the same as the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0 you linked, marking this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of downgrading the sdk for removing that warnings, you can filter the warnings by using Filter tag Regular Expressions. Just place the below line in Logcat search bar so that all the nativegetenable tags will be removed. This is the problem with API Level 17 SDK and cannot be removed except for filter option.

> ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$

copy, paste the above line so that all your warning messages with nativegetenabled tags will removed.

Comment: log cat is not a problem to me if it is not affected to the application. Does it mean that application does't affect this warning?

Comment: yes, that log cat message never effect application and they are unknown messages from emulator. don't exact description or else why they come but can surely say they doesn't effect application

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is not actual anymore. Intel x86 Atom images were problematic till today, but with the release of the Intel x86 Atom 4.3 image (API 18) the problem is gone. Just tested it and can confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the API 17 Emulator. You may use of API 16 or below. You might need to use real device if you really want to work with API 17.