# Unable to run android 2.2 emulator from eclipse

Tags: android

Hi i basically just started building apps for android, and i have been following some tutorials just to get started, but my apps won't run in 4.2. I get the message "Unfrotunatley, your app has closed...". So i created a android 2.2 emulator, and ran it fine, but in eclipse, it just shows "x" next to the 2.2 emulator, yet the 4.2 emulator displays perfectly.

How do i get the 2.2 emulator to work on eclipse, i have the SDK and all that, it just won't give me the option to run it. It works fine when not launching from eclipse.

Also, i know this could be classed as another question, but my program has 0 errors, and is almost identical to the tutorials that i've been following. I have tried to debug it and it says "42 frames skipped. Perhaps your program is running to much processes", so i went through the program, and nothing is actually happening, unless i hit the button.

logcat errors:

```
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf1f08 that was originally bound here
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service  com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf1f08 that was originally bound here
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-22 04:55:12.697: E/ActivityThread(740):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Im also getting this frequently:

```
01-22 05:00:10.832: W/Trace(740): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: i don't even know if it works in 2.x, i can't get the 2.2 emulator to even work. :c

Comment: may be any of the other uses-library or uses-feature is not there in the 2.2 emulator. (say camera or google maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

select your project selected, go to the Top "Run" Menu. Open "Run Configurations" and select your target virtual device android2.2 avd. Click apply, and then run the project.

follow the steps

1. Start the eclipse
2. Go to Windows->AVD manager-> select the Virtual device -> click start
3. Right click the project -> select run as-> run configuration and the same virtual device

   ```
        Your application should load now
   ```

   check this link

[Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

Comment: That was one of the first things i tried, but i simply doesn't even display there.

Comment: Did you create avd for android 2.2

Comment: well I've done that, it is similar to what you said last time. I changed the name of the device because it had a "." in the actual name, and i thought it mite not accept that. I changed it and it still doesn't work. This is the current error: unknown target in 'android 8' in <destination folder> I know that this error is just stupid, because i can run it perfectly when not in eclipse

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie try the above link

Comment: so only one idea just uninstall android version and install again

Comment: :C i was hoping i wouldn't have to uninstall anything... But i will give it a try

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie k dude...according to my opinion you just uninstall and install again.

Comment: Sweet, installed eclipse and Android SDK separately rather than in the bundle and works beautifully. Cheers man

Answer (score 1):

```
Im also getting this frequently:

01-22 05:00:10.832: W/Trace(740): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

For avoid this you can filter it out by Below Way.

Go to DDMS-->Select you Package name from **Saved Filter** and double click on it--> **Inside by Log Message** Write `^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$` --> Click Ok.

Thats All you will not get `Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0` this line Frequently.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie: Welcome, but you should upvote this Answer if it somehow helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Android SDK API 17 that floods LogCat with warning messages like:

Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

This makes it hard to see real messages. The message does not appear with older API versions. Until the bug has been fixed the messages can be suppressed using this filter:

```
^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$
```

It is a bug introduced in the latest revision of the tools... Google is working on a fix on the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this to your manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0