# getting warning like this while developing an android app

Tags: android

when i execute my android code in emulator, my log cat is displaying errors like this

```
02-26 05:23:49.800: W/Trace(799): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 05:23:49.800: W/Trace(799): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 05:23:49.800: W/Trace(799): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 05:23:49.800: W/Trace(799): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 05:23:49.800: W/Trace(799): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

due to this iam not facing any problem but i don't know why it is getting like that..
it won't stop until i close the app in emulator. after closing the app my log cat is giving this msg..

```
02-26 05:26:33.859: I/Choreographer(799): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

iam not doing any big app.. but for basic hello world also iam facing this issue.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of emulator system introduced in api level 17.

So until the bug is fixed you can do any of the following

1. use emulator with api 16 or lower
2. or if you need emulator with api 17 you can use the following filter in logcat

   ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$

It will not harm any of your task, just a spam.

You will find similar answers in this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

here is the issue reported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39723