# insert the data in database when keyboard's done button is click in android

Tags: android, database

I want to know that exact what should I do when the keyboard's DONE button is presses while inserting the data into the database?

I am using here like multiple edittext and when it come to the last edit button I have to insert all the data into the database..

```
private static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE_BUSINESSINFO=

"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUSINESS + "(" +

COL_BID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
COL_COMPANY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_ADD1 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +
COL_ADD2 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +
COL_ADD3 + " TEXT ,"+
COL_CITY +" TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_PROVINCE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_POSTCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +
COL_TEL1 + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_TEL2 + " TEXT ,"+
COL_WEBSITE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_TWITTER + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_FACEBOOK + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
COL_WELBO + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")" ;                                                

    private  static final String CREATE_BUSINESS_RECORD = "INSERT INTO "
        + TABLE_BUSINESS + " (" + COL_COMPANY_NAME + ", " 
                                + COL_ADD1+","
                                + COL_ADD2+","
                                + COL_ADD3+","
                                + COL_CITY+","
                                + COL_PROVINCE+","
                                + COL_POSTCODE+","
                                + COL_TEL1+","
                                + COL_TEL2+","
                                + COL_WEBSITE+","
                                + COL_EMAIL+","
                                + COL_TWITTER+","
                                + COL_FACEBOOK+","
                                + COL_WELBO
        + ") VALUES (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);";                         

           public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE_BUSINESSINFO);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BUSINESS_RECORD);
    }

          public void inserRecord(EditText edtxt_company, EditText edtxt_add1,
        EditText edtxt_add2, EditText edtxt_add3, EditText edtxt_city,
        EditText edtxt_province, EditText edtxt_postcode,
        EditText edtxt_tel1, EditText edtxt_tel2, EditText edtxt_website,
        EditText edtxt_email, EditText edtxt_twitter,
        EditText edtxt_facebook, EditText edtxt_welbo) {

    /*SQLiteDatabase mdb1=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();*/

    ContentValues record = new ContentValues();

    record.put("companyname", edtxt_company.toString());
    record.put("address1", edtxt_add1.toString());
    record.put("address2", edtxt_add2.toString());
    record.put("address3", edtxt_add3.toString());
    record.put("city", edtxt_city.toString());
    record.put("province", edtxt_province.toString());
    record.put("postcode", edtxt_postcode.toString());
    record.put("tel1", edtxt_tel1.toString());
    record.put("tel2", edtxt_tel2.toString());
    record.put("website", edtxt_website.toString());
    record.put("email", edtxt_email.toString());
    record.put("twitter", edtxt_twitter.toString());
    record.put("facebook", edtxt_facebook.toString());
    record.put("welbo", edtxt_welbo.toString());

    mDb.insert(CREATE_DB_TABLE_BUSINESSINFO, null,record); }

          IN MAINACTIVITY....FOR ADDING THE DATA.....


        @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                     if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                         Log.i("Insert Successfully","Insert");
                             addrow();
                          }
                    return false;
                }
                private void addrow() {
                    try
                    {
                        mDbHelper2.inserRecord(edtxt_company, edtxt_add1,edtxt_add2, edtxt_add3,edtxt_city, edtxt_province,edtxt_postcode,edtxt_tel1,edtxt_tel2,edtxt_website,edtxt_email, edtxt_twitter, edtxt_facebook, edtxt_welbo);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: You should write the necessary code to insert into the database...

Comment: After the Toast statement directly?? Because the EditorActionListener has the value of e1 EditText only but in my layout i have multiple EditTexts so how to fatch all the value and store it in database??

Comment: I am only set the listener on my last Edittext so i want to know that how to fatch all the edittext's value and store it into the database when DONE button is pressed from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**make one**

```
class DatabaseHelper
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    SQLiteDatabase dbms1;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor records;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,"UserDatabase", null,1);
        Log.i("Information", "Database Created");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void createTable(){
        try{
            dbms1=getWritableDatabase();
            String sql1="create table if not exists user(_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text not null,emailid text,gender text,username text,password text,birthdate text,phonenumber text,admin boolean,image BLOB);";
            Log.i("haiyang:createDB=", sql1);
            dbms1.execSQL(sql1);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.i("SQLiteException",e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            dbms1.close();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.i("SQLiteException",e.toString());
        }
    }
    public boolean inserRecord(String name,String emailid,String gender,String username,String password,String birthdate,String phonenumber,boolean admin,Drawable drawableResource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)drawableResource).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        ContentValues record=new ContentValues();
        record.put("name",name);
        record.put("emailid",emailid);
        record.put("gender",gender);
        record.put("username",username);
        record.put("password",password);
        record.put("birthdate",birthdate);
        record.put("phonenumber",phonenumber);
        record.put("admin",admin);
        record.put("image",out.toByteArray());

        try{
            dbms1=this.getWritableDatabase();
            dbms1.insert("user", null,record);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.i("SQLiteException",e.toString());
        }
            return true;
    }
}
```

after you have to create object of

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
dbHelper.createTable();
```

now call `insert` method of `DatabaseHelper class`

`dbHelper.insertRecord(....arguments....);`

where you have written **Toast**

Comment: Sir here u create a method insertRecord with String argument.I am also using the String in the DatabaseHelper class but when i call that method in my activity class, as you write dbHelper.insertRecord(....arguments....);in this argument i use the edittext value so its conflict because type mismatch...in datahelper we are using the String as an argument while in activity class we use exittext as argument..Now what is the solution of this??

Comment: Thank you sir for your guidance and slove that problem regard type cast by myself but problem is that the table is not generated. I already has a restaurent database and i create a table xyz intend of user. Now what was the problem regarding your solution?

Comment: I convert in the database class like this : public boolean inserRecord(EditText edtxt_company, EditText edtxt_add1)            {                                                       ContentValues record=new ContentValues();
   
 
         record.put("companyname",edtxt_company.toString());
         record.put("address1",edtxt_add1.toString());}

Comment: :in logcat  Log.i("Information", "Database Created"); this line is displayed but "Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0" is displayed so many times..1000 or more times

Comment: Log.i("haiyang:createDB=", sql1);..is not display in logcat that means the table is not generated with your current code.

Comment: sir m sorry to tell u that table is not created..:(

Comment: before insert method call dbHelper.createTable(); in your main activity.

Comment: Sorry sir again table is not created..:( :(

Comment: 03-07 04:47:54.252: I/Information(790): Database Created
03-07 04:48:09.142: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(790): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-07 04:48:10.982: D/dalvikvm(790): GC_CONCURRENT freed 542K, 19% free 2962K/3620K, paused 16ms+47ms, total 260ms

Comment: I can change the code and the table is created and the default value is also inserted but the actual values is not inserted..I edit my code. U just check that why the data is not inserted from the edittext.

Comment: EditText edtxt_add2, EditText edtxt_add3, EditText edtxt_city,
        EditText edtxt_province, EditText edtxt_postcode,
        EditText edtxt_tel1, EditText edtxt_tel2, EditText edtxt_website,

where is the method name insertRecord
        EditText edtxt_email, EditText edtxt_twitter,
        EditText edtxt_facebook, EditText edtxt_welbo) {

Comment: plz pass the string as argument not Edittext as argument.

Comment: before calling insert method saw the value in Toast.so you can get idea that value will goes right in argument. after check value at insertmethod using log.i(... arguments ...)

Comment: the method is in the mainactivity but now i change the code in that the method is addrow() while press the DONE button from keyboard and in addrow() method i put the insertRecord method..

Comment: you just have to call insertMethod ,when done button is clicked.at that time pass string values as argument.

Comment: you check my code in that i add the insertRecord in addRow() and addRow() method calls when DONE button is pressed.

Comment: Do you know the log cat?, display that value in logcat so you can see that actual value at received side.

Comment: means insert method is not call properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

Comment: this is the only problem that insert is not done at the keyboard's DONE button is pressed..:(

Comment: http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-sqlite-database.html

Comment: thank you sir but i think that i have a problem in this code..         @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == 
         KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND || actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) 
       {
            }
      return false;
     }                            NOT ENTER IN THIS METHOD..FOR DOWN BUTTON FROM THE KEYBOARD..