# Implicit "Submit" after hitting Done on the keyboard at the last EditText

Tags: android

I've used some apps where when I fill my username, then go to my password, if I hit "Done" on the keyboard, the login form is automatically submitted, without me having to click the submit button. How is this done?

Comment: Try this link answer... [insert the data in database when keyboard's done button is click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244123/insert-the-data-in-database-when-keyboards-done-button-is-click-in-android)

Comment: Quick link to the docs: [Specify the Input Method Action](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Try this:

In your layout put/edit this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

In your activity put this (e. g. in onCreate):

```
 // your text box
 EditText edit_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit);

 edit_txt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
             submit_btn.performClick();
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Where `submit_btn` is your submit button with your onclick handler attached.

Comment: `submit_btn.performClick();` is burning my eyes. Srsly? Why not call the submit method?

Comment: @LaurentMeyer Simulating user input is usually better than directly calling the underlying logic in these situations. For example, the submit button might be disabled currently, so performClick() would do nothing (as intended), but if you called the submit method directly, you'd have to check that the button wasn't disabled first. It will also play the "click" sound as though the button were tapped, etc.

Comment: @LaurentMeyer What do you mean by UI sensitive? And 5 people in the last 6 months, sure. Give them time and people will probably agree with me too. ;)

Comment: Let's consider that you change UI, that use the button for something else. The code will be a real mess and even worse, you need to have really extensive test procedures to detect that kind of bug. Even worse is when you share UI component with such practices.

Comment: Although an answer that sets you in the right direction, "put this and put that" doesn't really explain anything.. For more info: [Specify the Input Method Action](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action).

Comment: TWIMC, using `imeActionLabel` in my EditText was disabling all this behavior. Watch out

Comment: Remember add android:maxLines="1" & android:inputType="text" to your EditText.

Answer (score 35):

### Simple and effective solution with Kotlin

Extend `EditText`:

```
fun EditText.onSubmit(func: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->

       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           func()
       }

       true

    }
}
```

Then use the new method like this:

```
editText.onSubmit { submit() }
```

Where `submit()` is something like this:

```
fun submit() {
    // call to api
}
```

### More generic extension

```
fun EditText.on(actionId: Int, func: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, receivedActionId, _ ->

       if (actionId == receivedActionId) {
           func()
       }

        true
    }
}
```

And then you can use it to listen to your event:

```
email.on(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT, { confirm() })
```

Answer (score 29):

You need to set the IME Options on your `EditText`.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/some_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Whatever"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Then add a `OnEditorActionListener` to the view to listen for the "done" action.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.some_view);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // TODO do something
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Official API doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#ActionEvent

Answer (score 6):

This is how it is done

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //do something
        }
        return false;
   }
});
```

Don't forget to add following

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

**actionDone** in your EditText.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file inside your edittext tag add below snippet

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Then inside your Java class, write the below code

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int id, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) { 
            //do something here 
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810268/5417224)

```
fun EditText.onSubmit(func: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            clearFocus() // if needed 
            hideKeyboard()
            func()
        }
        true
    }
}

fun EditText.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 EditText edit_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit);

 edit_txt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
// which is u had set a imeoption
         if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
             submit_btn.performClick();
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

add the following line in edittext

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

```
etParola = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etParola); 
 btnGiris = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGiris);
  etParola.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    btnGiris.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

 and;


layout xml etParola
android:imeOptions="actionDone" add
```

Comment: This exactly the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294386). You should explain a bit how you think this solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signinscr_userName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/userName"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/signinscr_password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

in the java file

```
EditText userNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinscr_userName);
EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinscr_password);

passwordField.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
        //Do your operation here.
        return false;
    }
});
```