# Android <input type=“number”> confirm/enter button doesn't work

Tags: android, html, input

I have a form I'm trying to use on my Android phone which uses `<input type="number">`, but it does not submit when you press enter, it only moves to the next input box.

Is there any way to make the enter key on an Android submit the form instead?

[image]

Comment: post your code plz ...

Answer (score 1):

Implement     setOnEditorActionListener to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise, you first need to add the following XML attribute to your `EditText` widget:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

And somewhere in your activity, perhaps in the `onCreate()` method, add this:

```
 EditText edittext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MY_EDITTEXT);

 edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
             // Add the code for submitting here
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
 });
```

You can also take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217582/implicit-submit-after-hitting-done-on-the-keyboard-at-the-last-edittext) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In default android webview always will focus next input element on press enter button. Also, don't use jquery focus out option in android and it will make problem some other android devices.