# Android - EditTextPreference does not close keyboard once dialog dismissed

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

I'm building a settings screen using `PreferenceFragment` within `PreferenceActivity`.  Everything works fine other than an annoying issue where the soft keyboard stays visible after an `EditTextPreference` dialog has been closed, either by tapping Cancel, OK or tapping outside the dialog.

This is the first app I've built using API level 15 (4.0.3).  My previous app was for API level 8 (2.2) and just used `PreferenceActivity` for its settings (no fragment).  In that app, the keyboard always closes automatically on tapping Cancel, OK or outside the dialog - no code required.

Is it now normal to have to code the closing of the keyboard after dismissing an `EditTextPreference` dialog?  If so which event to I need to use to trap this?

Comment: you could set android:imeOptions="actionDone", once done is pressed it will automatically close the keyboard, I think keyboard should be closed when Edittext lose the focus

Comment: tapping the Done/Finished button on the keyboard just closes the keyboard and leaves the EditTextPreference dialog on screen.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217582/implicit-submit-after-hitting-done-on-the-keyboard-at-the-last-edittext

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. It is very annoying.