# How to execute equation using numeric keypad enter key?

Tags: java, android, input, keypad

I'm trying to make my first apk using java and android studio and I've been stuck for hours.
Basically it just does some math. The tutorial I started with implements a Calculate button to execute the equation based on user input, but I really want to use the enter key on the keypad and eliminate the calculate button, or at least execute the Calculate button when you press enter.
Using the numeric keypad's enter key advances you to the next line of user input. When all input has been added it changes to a check-mark but pressing it just hides the keypad. It doesn't do the math and provide results.
I'm hoping someone can point me in the rite direction.

```
package com.sativa.beeralator;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Objects;

import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText input5;
    private EditText input1;
    private EditText input2;
    private EditText input3;
    private EditText input4;
    private TextView tv_result;
    private TextView tv_result2;
    private String GetString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input5 = findViewById(R.id.et_input5);
        input1 = findViewById(R.id.et_input1);
        input2 = findViewById(R.id.et_input2);
        input3 = findViewById(R.id.et_input3);
        input4 = findViewById(R.id.et_input4);

        Button bt_calculate = findViewById(R.id.bt_calculate);

        tv_result = findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        tv_result2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_result2);

        bt_calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
                makeCalculations();


            }
        });
    }

    private void makeCalculations() {
            double doorfee = Double.parseDouble(input5.getText().toString());
            double people = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
            double beersperhour = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
            double hours = Double.parseDouble(input3.getText().toString());
            double contributions = doorfee * people;
            double cost = Double.parseDouble(input4.getText().toString());
            double result = Math.ceil(people * beersperhour * hours / 24);
            double result2 = (result * cost) - contributions;

            String sValue = String.format("%,.0f", result);
            String sValue2 = String.format("%,.2f", (Math.abs(result2)));

            tv_result.setText(String.format(" Required cases = %s", sValue));

            if (result2 >= 0) {
                tv_result2.setText(String.format(" Cost = $%s", sValue2));
            } else {
                tv_result2.setText(String.format(" Profit = $%s", sValue2));
            }

        }

}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit "Submit" after hitting Done on the keyboard at the last EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217582/implicit-submit-after-hitting-done-on-the-keyboard-at-the-last-edittext)

Comment: Thank you. That is the info I was looking for. I'm getting close. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
input5.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```