# pulltorefresh android 4.1 and higher

Tags: android, listview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm using the pullToRefresh library:

```
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/pull/40
```

But the list cant be moved if the android version is bigger than 4.0

LogCat shows emulator warnings, but they are not related.

How can I solve the problem moving the list?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The problem is related to the emulator and it should not cause any errors with functionality of your application. It happens often only on 4.2 emulator or a device.

[Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)