# Android broadcast receiver listening outgoing call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android. I am working on broadcastreceiver. I want to create a receiver listening outgoing call. What I expected is when ever out going call is made write logcat " It is Ok" .
But it show message on log as "unexpected value from nativegetenabledtags".

Following is my manifestFile.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.vogella.android.receiver.phone.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Following is receiver Class

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
              String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
              Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", state);
              if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String phoneNumber = extras
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", phoneNumber);
              }
            }  
            }

}
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: Are there any error messages or exceptions within the log cat. if so please post them

Comment: put errorlog or stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the exact reason but for your class name you need to put a dot (.) in the front. Like below.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver" >
```

I'm not sure if this is your exact issue but without the . will cause you other issues if this isn't the reason

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

Add this filter to the LogCat: ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)).*$

It is a bug introduced in the latest revision of the tools... Google is working on a fix on the next version