# It shows " UI unfortunately stop"

Tags: java, android, numbers, factors

This code contains no error, but on running it shows "unfortunately stops".
The code is for finding the factors of number; I know it should be simple, but I am new in android technology and I need some help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText edttxt;
    Button btn;
    int i=0 ;
    String str;
    TextView textview1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textview1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                i=Integer.parseInt(edttxt.getText().toString());
                if(i==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int j=2;j<(i/2);j++)
                    {
                        if(i%j==0)
                        {
                            a.add(j);
                        }
                    }
                    int arraylistSize = a.size();
                    for(int i = 0; i < arraylistSize; i++) {
                        textview1.setText(a.get(i));
                        textview1.setText("*");
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
        );
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the logcat is:-

```
08-14 21:13:31.381: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:31.381: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.051: W/Resources(793): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080002}
08-14 21:13:32.281: W/Resources(793): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080003}
08-14 21:13:32.291: W/Resources(793): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080005}
08-14 21:13:32.492: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.492: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.711: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.821: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.951: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:32.951: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.021: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.232: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.232: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.281: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.281: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.291: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.302: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.321: D/gralloc_goldfish(793): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-14 21:13:33.581: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.681: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.691: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:33.691: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.011: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.011: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.192: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.192: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.301: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.301: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.701: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.701: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.765: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:34.771: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.293: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.293: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.373: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.373: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.731: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:35.731: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.063: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.063: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.281: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.322: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.452: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.461: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.882: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.941: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:36.992: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.021: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.341: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.351: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.401: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.401: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.971: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:37.981: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.061: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.061: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.461: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.461: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.521: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:38.521: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.081: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.081: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.521: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.521: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.641: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:39.651: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.101: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.101: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.653: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.653: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.691: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:40.721: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.158: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.161: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.201: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.236: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.716: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:41.761: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.101: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.101: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.171: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.211: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.481: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.481: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.713: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.713: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.851: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:42.851: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.181: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.371: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.371: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.441: D/dalvikvm(793): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 8% free 2670K/2892K, paused 59ms+90ms, total 759ms
08-14 21:13:43.776: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.776: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.801: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:43.801: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.321: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.332: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.441: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.441: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.772: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:44.792: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.225: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.225: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.284: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.284: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.714: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.714: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.851: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:45.851: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.141: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.141: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.311: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.311: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.791: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.791: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.821: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:46.821: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.301: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.301: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.331: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.331: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.641: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.641: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.881: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.881: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.951: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:47.951: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.372: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.372: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.512: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.512: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.872: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.872: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.903: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
08-14 21:13:48.921: W/Trace(793): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: `This code contains no error, but on running it shows "unfortunately stops"`.  If you're learning, you should learn about the difference between compile time errors and runtime errors.  Your code DOES contain errors, otherwise it would run fine.  You cannot get a runtime error until you have fixed all of the compile time errors.

Comment: You've posted the wrong part of logcat.  Please look again for the exception stack trace. If you don't know how, then please use Google.

Comment: The Logcat output you have posted is not what we are asking for. Run the app. Let it crash. Go to Logcat view. Copy and paste the trace starting from "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" until the end. Also, check for ""(empty string) in the `EditText` before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0) The messages you are seeing in the debug log are a problem with the emulator and can be just filtered out.  I am not sure what the real problem is yet, but one issue is the code

```
int arraylistSize = a.size();
for(int i = 0; i < arraylistSize; i++) {
    textview1.setText(a.get(i));
    textview1.setText("*");
 }
```

It should probably be more like:

```
int arraylistSize = a.size();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i < arraylistSize; i++) {
    sb.append(a.get(i));
    if (i != arraylistSize -1)
    {
        sb.append("*");
    }
 }
textview1.setText(sb.toString());
```

as it is going to change the value of the text so fast that you won't see anything but the last "*".  If you filter the logcat as per the link, you will probably see a null pointer exception somewhere.

Another suggestion is to replace:

```
i=Integer.parseInt(edttxt.getText().toString());
```

With:

```
try
{
    if (edttxt.getText() != null && edttxt.getText().toString() != null)
    {
        i=Integer.parseInt(edttxt.getText().toString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("usbEffects", "Error parsing", ex);
    i=0;
}
```

As this will defend the code but still tell you why it failed.

Comment: Good answer. But you overlooked one detail. This would produce output like `4*2*1*`. Expected output would (or should?) be `4*2*1`. Make changes to the `for-loop` to fix this issue. Also, advice the user to check for `"" (empty string)` in the `EditText` before parsing it to an `Integer`. Or else, a `NumberFormatException` would be thrown at runtime.