# use menu in one of the class of viewpager

Tags: java, android, menu, android-viewpager

I am new in android, so I have made an application where I am swiping activities from one activity to another. But one of my activities has a list which itself has some animations, which I select using menu. Now after doing swiping through view pager, list is being shown but the menu to this particular list is not showing, which contains the different animations style on my list. I have used listview. I have used onCreateOptionMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() method. My code is given below for this particular activity.

```
public class TabFragmentClass extends Fragment {

    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    ListView list_view=null;
    Animation animation=null;
    int mode=R.id.TranslateAnimation1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        list_view=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list_view.setFadingEdgeLength(0);

        ArrayList<String> ar_li=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            ar_li.add("item: "+(i+1));
        }
        MainAdapter mAdapter=new MainAdapter(getActivity(),ar_li,metrics);
        list_view.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,0,"TranslateAnimation1");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 0, "TranslateAnimation2");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, 0, "ScaleAnimation");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 4, 0, "fade_in");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 5, 0, "hyper_space_out");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 6, 0, "wave_scale");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 7, 0, "push_left_in");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 8, 0, "push_left_out");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mode=item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    class MainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater minflator;
        ArrayList<String> ar_string;
        DisplayMetrics metrics;
        TextView txt_view;

        public MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> ar_string, 
          DisplayMetrics metrics) {
            super(context, 0, ar_string);
            this.context=context;
            this.minflator=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.ar_string=ar_string;
            this.metrics=metrics;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String str=this.ar_string.get(position);

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=minflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,null);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF202020);
                txt_view=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                txt_view.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

                convertView.setTag(txt_view);
            }
            else
            {
                convertView.getTag();   

            }
            txt_view.setText(str);

            switch (mode) {
                case R.id.TranslateAnimation1:
                    animation=new TranslateAnimation(metrics.widthPixels/2,0,0,0);
                    System.out.println("animated value:::::"+animation);
                    break;
                case R.id.TranslateAnimation2:
                    animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,metrics.heightPixels, 0);
                    break;
                case R.id.ScaleAnimation:
                    animation=new ScaleAnimation((float)1.0,(float)1.0, (float)0, (float)1.0);
                    break;
                case R.id.fade_in:
                    animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_fade_in);
                    break;
                case R.id.hyper_space_out:
                    animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.hyper_space_out);
                    break;
                case R.id.wave_scale:
                    animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.wave_scale);
                    break;
                case R.id.push_left_in:
                    animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_in);
                    break;
                case R.id.push_left_out:
                    animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_out);
                    break;      
                default:
                    break;
            }

            animation.setDuration(500);
            convertView.startAnimation(animation);
            animation=null;
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` on your `onStart`method or  to show menu on `action bar` in your `fragment`. Something like this :

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onStart();
    }
```

You can also call this function on your `onCreateView` or `onCreate`method.

Comment: but now I am getting this message,how to reslove it:- I/Choreographer(1181): Skipped 113 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I/System.out(1181): menu

Comment: It looks like you are doing a fair amount of work in that method that should be done off the UI thread. Try to use AsyncTask and Threads to reduce load on UI thread.

Comment: I am using this,but I am too confused what to put in doInBackGround() method.

Answer (score 0):

my problem has been resolved,I have seen this error on my logcat with the message and the error is  W/Trace(): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 of which I got the answer from this link:- [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)
and my application is running fine on device without giving any such error and message.
Thank you