# Android Intent Never Launches Sound Recorder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, logcat, android-audiorecord

So I have a sound recorder - and when I run it in the emulator and click new recording - it launches the default sound recorder and it works perfect. However when I attempt to click new recording on the phone I have - nothing happens. I actually have two of the exact same phone - it does nothing on both. I see a bit of interesting activity in my logcat - but I'm not sure exactly what it means.

Any tips/suggestions/answers are greatly appreciated.

http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/

### LOGCAT:

```
    startActivity---,intent=Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
12-26 01:18:18.401: I/fengjun1010(5430): ---null
12-26 01:18:18.402: E/Ringdroid(5430): Error: Error launching Sound Recorder
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

Comment: Not the same issue at all.

Comment: I think the issue is with the device

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate!! It is a totally different issue... PS - I think the moderators are speed reading again

Comment: From the logs, it is clear that Ringdroid is failing to start. Can you install another sound recorded on your phones and choose that instead? If the other app works, it seems like a problem with RingDroid.