# Android : Logcat tag filtering

Tags: android

I got to know that we can get debug prints from particular module through adb using

```
adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager 
adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager
```

But if i issue the command like( Explicitly make the spell wrongly )

```
adb logcat -s Unity Activitymanager, something is going wrong
```

I just want to know is there any adb command to list the entire module name that we can use along `adb logcat -S unity ******` to print module related info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0

Answer (score 0):

There is no adb command that gives a list of tags that you can filter the logcat output on, because there is no limitation at all on what a tag contains, except one of length.  At the API level, each log call provides a tag to go with the log text - many apps will make the tag in some way related to the modulename that the code calling log resides in, but there is nothing that enforces this.

Apps can and do do unexpected things with the tag - for example using an incrementing counter as the tag, or using a timestamp!  Perhaps more useful is the technique of passing a tag consisting of a fixed suffix followed by the hashcode of the object being logged.