# How to hide NativeCrypto messages from Logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

Checked Solutions: [Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0)

My Logcat is only showing the following unused messages with a fast execution.

```
10-12 10:35:19.661: D/NativeCrypto(7146): Entering sslRead, caller requests to read 1  bytes timeout=0...
10-12 10:35:19.661: D/NativeCrypto(7146): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x1b27ad8,     appData=0x17c7e60
10-12 10:35:19.661: D/NativeCrypto(7146): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x1b27ad8, appData=0x17c7e60
```

I have check the given solution, but it didn't hide anything inside logcat. I don't know why this message comes only some selected apps.

Is there any fix solution for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know why its showing .I think its for map.

Anyways.. to hide this you can use the  [same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0) with a little change. Just use 
`^(?!.*(NativeCrypto)).*$` in `by Log Tag` TextBox.